# How to format opening braces in C++ methods with astyle?

Tags: c++, astyle

Is a common practice to move function's opening brace to next line.
How to apply this in class method with astyle (code beautifier)?

example:

```
// this is an initial C++ code
class Class
{
public:
    static int foo(bool x) {
        if (x) {
            return 42;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

modified version should be:

```
class Class
{
public:
    static int foo(bool x)
    { // this brace in next line
        if (x) {
            return 42;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

All my attempts working only for global functions.

Comment: This is likely related to this issue: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3259702&group_id=2319&atid=102319

Answer (score 2):

Both `--style=kr / -A3` and `--style=linux / -A8` option should apply to class methods as well.

From the docs:

> Brackets are broken from namespace, class, and function definitions. Brackets are attached to statements within a function.

Comment: Are you also using the `--indent-classes` option?

Comment: `--indent-classes` switch only increase indent level (for access modifiers too (_public:_ in example))

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that `--style=ansi` does this in current releases of AStyle (v2.03 here).

Answer (score -3):

This thing really depends on one's preference and his team's preference. 
Most IDE's follow the braces that you gave in your first example. They also use colored fillers to point out the starting brace and the endling brace.
If you bring your mouse pointer to the ending brace, it will color its starting brace too.

Comment: I would like to downvote your answer, because you it seems you didn't read the question. He didn't ask for an opinion about formatting. But as you are new, you will go on unscathed - for now :-)