# How to set Astyle so that it does not format two braces on the same line

Tags: c++, coding-style, astyle

When encountering the following code,

```cpp
while(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {x = x * 10 + c - 48; c = getchar();}
```

Astyle will format it to

```cpp
while(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    x = x * 10 + c - 48;
    c = getchar();
}
```

I don't want this to happen.

So how to set Astyle so that it does not format two braces on the same line?

Comment: There is only one true brace style, no? :P Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052597/how-to-format-opening-braces-in-c-methods-with-astyle

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 no